# Função time() está retornando o mesmo valor sempre

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
from time import time

class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, value, timestamp=time()):
        self.value = value
        self.created_at = timestamp
```

Criando uma instância e vendo o seu timestamp:

```
t1 = Transaction()
t1.created_at
'1554492682.907307'
```

Criando agora uma segunda instância e também vendo o seu timestamp:

```
t2 = Transaction()
t2.created_at
'1554492682.907307'
```

Repare que o timestamp do objeto `t2` é o mesmo do objeto do objeto `t1` e não foram criados ao mesmo tempo logicamente.

Por que o argumento que possui um valor padrão está sendo calculado uma única vez e repetindo para todos objetos subsequentes?

Comment: Mesmo esquema de sempre: qualquer dúvida é só perguntar. Se discordar que é duplicada me avisa que reavaliamos o fechamento.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Na resposta que você marcou diz que este comportamento ocorre para somente tipos mutáveis como "dicionários, listas, etc". Na minha dúvida, o atributo created_at é do tipo float, mas float não é imutável?

Comment: A ideia é: o valor padrão do argumento é definido na hora da definição da classe, ou seja, sua função time será chamada apenas uma vez e usará o retorno como valor padrão.